# Set a variable equal to result of Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables - membership and renewals2017. I want to set a variable called $email to the value of the following query, but I am not sure I am doing this correctly. The tables are inner joined by Member_ID in the membership table and m_id in the renewals2017 table. The value of the email is in the membership table. The reason I want to set the variable $email is because I will be using that value to send an email. Here is my query:

```
SET $email = ("SELECT membership.E_Mail_Address FROM membership INNER
JOIN renewals2017 ON renewals2017.m_id = membership.Member_ID";);
```

If there is a better way to do this, or this is not correct, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: First you need to get rid of the `SET`. You then loop over successful results and grab the email from it, then assign it to a variable. Use a `WHERE` clause also which will work in your favor.

Comment: check this, it has a simple example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php

Comment: Look over the example here http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: Please don't suggest or use plain ol MySQL for PHP. Use MySQLI, with an I at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is (currently) no keyword *SET* in PHP, so just declare your variable by assigning a value to it.

Use [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) to connect to the database, [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to perform a query, and then [fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to iterate over each returned record - see the example below:

```
//update the parameters per your credentials below
$connection = mysqli_connect("databaseServer", "userName", "password", "databaseName");
$query = $connection->query("SELECT membership.E_Mail_Address FROM membership INNER JOIN renewals2017 ON renewals2017.m_id = membership.Member_ID");
while($result = $query->fetch_array(MSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $email = $result['E_Mail_Address']; //one for each resulting record
}
```

You could also create the connection object-oriented style - like below:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("databaseServer", "userName", "password", "databaseName);
```